# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ... from loader

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compilation, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm using IntelliJ in Windows 7 and after a recent sudden change to my development system (not device) I'm stuck with the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` thrown by `System.loadLibrary()` for loading a native `.so` library

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ... from loader
```

I tried every fix suggested on SO with no success including:

- Rebuilding the app and recreating modules structure from scratch
- Cleaning IntelliJ cache and restarting Intellj

I have my .so libraries in the `libs` folder

- libs

  - armeabi
  - x86

Answer (score 3):

The `.so` library which was not loading was in my main app. The main app is dependent on another module named `X` which have a .so file in the following hierarchy:

- libs

  - armeabi-v7a

I've noticed that adding this module to the project prevented main module native libs to be loaded.

It seems that there's a conflict between both `libs` folders so the only crazy fix that let both `.so` files get loaded was to rename `armeabi-v7a` folder in module X to `armeabi` and now everything is OK.