# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader error in device

Tags: android, ocr

I tried to run the OCR sample project from this https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr. This project worked well in the **Emulator**. But when I tested with the **Device**, I got the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/mnt/asec/edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr-1/pkg.apk,libraryPath=/mnt/asec/edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr-1/lib]: findLibrary returned null
```

The testing device is samsung note3 and android version is 4.4.2. I would like to know that what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post more relevant logs

Comment: This seems like a missing so file problem. Make sure you have the relavant so file for your processor(arm/intel). Did you build the so file for all processor types? Can you run the play store app mentioned in the github page  - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr

Comment: This answer solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17675829/1156041. I created new folder named `libs` folder and copy the `.so` files into it.

Comment: Then how your project worked well on Emulator?

Comment: I didn't got `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. It run successfully in the Emulator.

Comment: Yes, I did @VinayWadhwa. But I still got `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.